# searching and replacing does not record in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How I record an action for this function?
Basically I have to do this and others actions everyday and always is the same.

[image: There is the error]

Comment: Please describe your situation, what you want to achieve and the problem you are having in more detail.

Comment: Hello @Reynaldo! Would you mind providing more information and details about your issue? Also, the code you have used would be of great help! Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> searching and replacing does not record in google sheets

That is right, the find and replace function is not accessible via Google App Scripts and is not therefore able to be recorded. You need to create your own code to accomplish a behavior similar to the behavior you want manually.

Here is one of many example ways of doing it: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/104157/auto-find-and-replace-in-google-sheets-with-scripts

Answer (score 0):

Thanks i used that code and i edited a litle bit.

```
function Herramienta() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1:A69').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1:A69').splitTextToColumns();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("a2:a69");
  var to_replace = "HH-";
  var replace_with = "";
  replaceInSheet(sheet,range, to_replace, replace_with);
function replaceInSheet(sheet, range, to_replace, replace_with) {
  //Confirm
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
  var spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var result = ui.alert(
     "Will update " + to_replace + " to " + replace_with + " ",
     'Are you sure you want to continue?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  // Process the user's response.
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {

    // User clicked "Yes".
    spread.toast("Will update " + to_replace + " to " + replace_with + " ", "ALERT");

    var data  = range.getValues();

    var oldValue="";
    var newValue="";
    var cellsChanged = 0;

    for (var row=0; row<data.length; row++) {
      for (var item=0; item<data[row].length; item++) {
        oldValue = data[row][item];
        newValue = data[row][item].replace(to_replace, replace_with);
        if (oldValue!=newValue)
        {
          cellsChanged++;
          data[row][item] = newValue;
        }
      }
    }
    range.setValues(data);
    spread.toast(cellsChanged + " cells changed", "STATUS");
  }
  else {
    // User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.
    spread.toast("No action taken", "ABANDONED");
  }
}
}
```